# How do I capture and then pass cookies to Ruby/Mechanize ( a workaround to log in)?

Tags: ruby, cookies, authentication, mechanize

This question is linked with my other question "[log in with browser and then ruby/mechanize takes it over?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166801/log-in-with-browser-and-then-ruby-mechanize-takes-it-over)"

I am not able to log into one website using Ruby/Mechanize so I was thinking if there is any workaround for the log-in part. After that I want my script to take over and do its job.

Could somebody suggest what is the best/easiest way to:

- capture all info (cookies and do I need anything else)?
- pass it to Ruby/Mechanize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how to pass cookies and headers to Mechanize. I do not need this workaround any more but I can recommend these Firefox addons for analyzing/saving/viewing cookies and HTTP headers. They helped me to find a solution:

- Live HTTP headers
- Firebug
- httpfox
- webdeveloper

Comment: Hey Radek, what was your issue exactly? What was the solution to the issue?

Comment: I think that the solution was either to add new field in mechanize that wasn't captured by mechanize so the login process can be successful or that the login required md5 not the username & password. Hope this helps.