# how to add new field to mechanize form (ruby/mechanize)

Tags: ruby, webforms, mechanize

there is a [public class method](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/WWW/Mechanize/Form/Field.html) to add field to mechanize form

I tried ..

```
#login_form.field.new('auth_login','Login')
#login_form.field.new('auth_login','Login')
```

and both gives me an error `undefined method "new" for #<WWW::Mechanize::Form::Field:0x3683cbc> (NoMethodError)`

I tried `login_form.field.new('auth_login','Login')` which gives me an error

```
mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize/page.rb:13 n `meta': undefined method `search' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

but at the time I submit the form. The field does not exist in html source. I want to add it so POST query sent by my script will contain **`auth_username=myusername&auth_password=mypassword&auth_login=Login`** So far it sends only **`auth_username=radek&auth_password=mypassword`** which might be why I cannot get logged in. Just my thought.

The script looks like

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'logger'

agent = WWW::Mechanize.new {|a| a.log = Logger.new("loginYOTA.log") }
agent.follow_meta_refresh = true #Mechanize does not follow meta refreshes by default, we need to set that option.

page = agent.get("http://www.somedomain.com/login?auth_successurl=http://www.somedomain.com/forum/yota?baz_r=1")


login_form = page.form_with(:method => 'POST')  

puts login_form.buttons.inspect
puts page.forms.inspect
#STDIN.gets

login_form.fields.each { |f| puts "#{f.name} : #{f.value}" }    

login_form['auth_username'] = 'radeks'
login_form['auth_password'] = 'TestPass01'

#login_form['auth_login'] = 'Login'     
#login_form.field.new('auth_login','Login')
#login_form.field.new('auth_login','Login')
#login_form.fields.each { |f| puts "#{f.name} : #{f.value}" }
#STDIN.gets 

page = agent.submit login_form


#Display welcome message if logged in

puts page.parser.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/table/tr/td[2]/div/strong").xpath('text()').to_s.strip
  puts
puts page.parser.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/table/tr/td[2]/div").xpath('text()').to_s.strip

output = File.open("login.html", "w") {|f| f.write(page.parser.to_html) }
```

The .inspect of the form looks like

```
[#<WWW::Mechanize::Form
 {name nil}
 {method "POST"}
 {action
  "http://www.somedomain.com/login?auth_successurl=http://www.somedomain.com/forum/yota?baz_r=1"}
 {fields
  #<WWW::Mechanize::Form::Field:0x36946c0 @name="auth_username", @value="">
  #<WWW::Mechanize::Form::Field:0x369451c @name="auth_password", @value="">}
 {radiobuttons}
 {checkboxes}
 {file_uploads}
 {buttons
  #<WWW::Mechanize::Form::Button:0x36943b4
   @name="auth_login",
   @value="Login">}>
]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is

```
login_form.add_field!(field_name, value = nil)
```

Here are the docs:

http://rdoc.info/projects/tenderlove/mechanize

The difference between this and the method WWW::Mechanize::Form::Field.new is not much, aside from the fact that there aren't many ways to add fields to a form. Here's how the add_field! method is implemented....you can see that it's exactly what you'd expect. It instantiates a Field object, then adds it to the form's 'fields' array. You wouldn't be able to do this in your code because the method "fields<<" is a private method inside "Form."

```
# File lib/www/mechanize/form.rb, line 65
  def add_field!(field_name, value = nil)
    fields << Field.new(field_name, value)
  end
```

On a side note, according to the docs you should be able to do the first variation you proposed:

```
login_form['field_name']='value'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @btelles: works! so what's difference between your code and http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/WWW/Mechanize/Form/Field.html public method class new for field?

Comment: I thought that `login_form['field_name']='value'` doesn't work because I was trying to add the field and not to modify. Maybe somebody can elaborate on that if one have more knowledge about that.

Comment: If you click the "show source" for the []= method, you'll see that the implementation creates a field if one doesn't already exist by running the "add_field!" method. It says "does a field already exist by that name?" if not, then "add_field!(field_name, value)"...

Answer (score 4):

another way how to add new field is to so at the time of posting the form

```
page = agent.post( url, {'auth_username'=>'myusername',   #existing field
                         'auth_password'=>'mypassword',   #existing field
                         'auth_login'=>'Login'})   #new field
```